# How to always make "this" keyword to reference the parent class (bind child methods to parent class)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, scope, this

here is the simplest form of my problem:

```js
class Service1 {
  constructor() { this.name = 'service1' }
  getThisName() { console.log('Name: ' + (this && this.name)) }
}

const service1 = new Service1();

service1.getThisName() // 'service1' => :)

function mapper(fn, ...params) {
  this.name = 'mapper';
  // ...params can be parsed or generated here
  fn(...params);
}

mapper(service1.getThisName) // undefined => :'(
```

I know I can `fn.bind(service1)` in the `mapper` function to solve the problem, but as `fn` is dynamic, I would prefer not to do that.
I have tried searching on how to get the parent class from child method but get no results.

I want `mapper` to be able to call a method of a class (or object) without loosing the this reference in a **readable** and **straightforward** way if possible. `mapper` is always called in the same context.

**Is there a way in javascript to solve this problem ?**

---

#### What I have tried

```js
function mapper(fn, serviceClass) {
  fn.bind(serviceClass)();
}
mapper(service1.getThisName, service1) // OK but is not readable and seems hacky
```

```js
function mapper(serviceClass, fnName) {
  serviceClass[fnName]();
}
mapper(service1, 'getThisName') // OK but autocompletion in the IDE don't work
```

```js
function mapper(fn) {
  fn();
}
mapper(service1.getThisName.bind(service1)) // the "best practice" but in my case not enougth readable
```

#### Real use case context

In the real use case scenario, the `mapper` is called `api2service`. As the name suggests, it is used with expressJs to map api routes to services. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```js
app.get(
  'get/all/users', // api endpoint
  api2service(
    userService.getAll, // getAll take filter as the first param
    ['req.query'] // req.query is the filter and is mapped AND parsed as the first param of the service function. Eg: {name: 'blah'}
  )
)
```

That code is repeated a lot of time and always called in the same context, that's why I need something **readable** over the strict respect of good practices.

Comment: What did you want `this` to represent in the `mapper` function body? In strict mode it will be undefined...

Comment: "*I know I can `fn.bind(service1)` in the mapper function to solve the problem*" but why not bind it *before* handing it off `mapper(service1.getThisName.bind(service1))`? You cannot bind an anonymous function you're given because you have no trace what to associate it with. But if you do it beforehand, there is no need for `mapper` to know anything. I personally prefer `mapper(() => service1.getThisName())` because the binding makes it look like a sandwich but it's basically the same thing - you ensure the correct `this` is maintained.

Comment: @trincot I want this to refer to the service1 class

Comment: @VLAZ Hi binding before to send as param also really trouble readability. I like the () => syntax also, but it is not convenient for the real use case where I need to dynamically map (and eventually parse) params of the function

Comment: So dispite its name, mapper would actually mutate the instance and not return anything?

Comment: @trincot I have edited my question, eventually, it could map functions params ^^

Comment: You can also just bind your methods to each instance at creation time. Point is that you need to do it *before* giving the function elsewhere. Not trying and figure out where it came from.

Comment: @CAWIDEV, I don't see how that makes it different. `mapper` still mutates the instance, and returns nothing. I wouldn't that call a mapper. A mapper typically *maps* data to other data (not mutating it) and *returns* that result.

Comment: As you seem to mutate the given instance completely (overwriting its only data member), is there a reason why you need an existing instance of the class at all? Is it a singleton?

Comment: @trincot the real use case is much more complex, service1 extends from baseService AND as you see in real use section, params ar taken from strings, mapped, parsed and even generated to be returned in the service function. But I don't think that is relevant to the question. I ll ad a coment to specify it anyway :)

Comment: OK, it remains unclear what you are really after. I see you have accepted an answer, so I'll move on.

Comment: It really should be `mapper(service1.getThisName.bind(service1))` or `mapper((...args) => service1.getThisName(...args))` - don't make `mapper` responsible for calling the method with the right context

Comment: @Bergi I know this may not be a good practice for 99% of case, but I am in a case where I really want to favor readability over contextualisation. And the mapper is **always** called in the same context. I'll provide details about that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the [bind operator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) is implemented, there's not much you can do about this. Apart from your attempts, you can automatically bind methods at construction time (see also https://github.com/sindresorhus/auto-bind):

```js
function autoBind(obj) {
    let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    for (let k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
        if (typeof proto[k] === 'function' && k !== 'constructor')
            obj[k] = proto[k].bind(obj)
    }
}

class Service1 {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'service1'
        autoBind(this);
    }
    getThisName() { console.log('Name: ' + (this && this.name)) }
}

function mapper(fn) {
    fn();
}

let srv = new Service1
mapper(srv.getThisName)
```

or use a binding Proxy:

```js
function Bound(obj) {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get(target, prop) {
            let el = target[prop];
            if(typeof el === 'function')
                return el.bind(target)
        }
    })
}

class Service1 {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'service1'
    }
    getThisName() { console.log('Name: ' + (this && this.name)) }
}

function mapper(fn) {
    fn();
}

let srv = new Service1
mapper(Bound(srv).getThisName)
```

Comment: I used the first version, I like it a lot because it allow me to seamlessly write my service in the api file. Thanks for such a qualitative answer :)

Comment: You're right. I thought I had made such a test and got different results. The code is indeed solid.